# Xilinx FPGA Editor + Line Names?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am playing around with the FPGA editor and looking at a Spartan3E. When I click the different lines the console displays what I guess is a name for each individual line:

What exactly do these mean? I know there are different line types and I'm guessing the different names (double, OMUX...etc) siginfy the different types but what do the numbers tell me? I can't find anywhere this is documented.

```
node = OMUX(10200,31745)
node = DOUBLE(9504,39237)
node = DOUBLE(12960,39237)
node = OMUX(10200,31745)
node = OMUX(6744,31745)
node = DOUBLE(9552,39201)
node = HUNIHEX(9408,38995)
node = HUNIHEX(5952,38967)
node = HUNIHEX(13088,39119)
node = HUNIHEX(2496,38883)
node = HUNIHEX(13112,39077)
node = HUNIHEX(2496,38799)
node = HLONG(-1208,39003)
node = HLONG(-1192,38979)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you're walking in uncharted territory. Xilinx has provided very little documentation on the low-level structure of their FPGAs.

That being said: the objects you're looking at are all different types of wires connecting elements in the FPGA. The names have to do with the length of the wires; for instance, OMUX is a very short wire, and HLONG is a much longer one. There are some more details on the routing structure of the Virtex-4 FPGA in section 6.6.6 of [*Generating the Communications
Infrastructure for Module-based Dynamic
Reconfiguration of FPGAs*](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~odiessel/papers/phdkoh.pdf). They won't match exactly with the Spartan-3E you're using, but there will likely be some similarities.

The numbers are almost certainly coordinates specifying the location of these specific wires within the FPGA.